# JMS Serializing/Deserializing mechanism

Tags: java, serialization, jms, deserialization

I would like to understand as to how JMS serializes and deserializes the content internally. From the [Javadoc of ObjectMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/ObjectMessage.html) I understand that the object needs to be Serializable. However, I cannot think of it as Javas serialization. I say this because JMS messages can be sent from non-java systems as well (also because it can be used as an endpoint in ESB configuration).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot think of it as Javas serialization

It is all the same.

> I say this because JMS messages can be sent from non-java systems as well

And they won't be able to deserialize the messages (without help from Java)

Comment: So, does it mean that JMS messages cannot be platform independent (as they need Java for its supporting libraries) ?

Comment: ObjectMessages are not platform independent, all the other message types are.

Comment: Thanks. I see that other extensions of Message are BytesMessage, MapMessage, StreamMessage, TextMessage. So, I now understand that all these are platform independent.

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken. JMS messages in `ObjectMessage` format essentially cannot be sent by a non-Java peer.